# Totally new to mips, can someone tell me where I'm going wrong in this project to reverse .byte and .word array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, reverse

I've been trying to figure out this project for my class where we take `daBeef` and `daGreeting` and save their reverses in `buffer1` and `buffer2`. So `buffer1` would have `0xcafebeef` and `buffer2` would have "etov" (I'm pretty sure this is what the assignment is asking at least). But like the title says I really have no clue where to begin with this and nothing the teacher has posted really helps with figuring this out. I have emailed him about it but he's notoriously slow at answering and tomorrow is Sunday and the project is due Monday (11-9-20) at 11:59 pm. So I figured it would be best to ask for help here in case he doesn't respond to my email in time or his response simply doesn't help.

Here is the code I have so far, again, I'm super new to mips and I don't really understand it so sorry if there are a bunch of glaring mistakes.

```
.data   # Do not change this data segment

daBeef:     .word  0xefbefeca
someSpace:  .space 4
daGreeting: .byte 'v','o','t', 'e'

daGarbage:  .byte 'D':100  # same as .byte 0x44:100

.data 0x100100a0   #starts next series of bytes at this address
buffer1:   .byte 'a':4   # where your first answer will reside
buffer2:   .byte 'b':4   # where your second answer will reside


.text
#read value from memory in daBeef and daGreeting
#write the value to the required memory space buffer1 and buffer2 in REVERSE ORDER
main:
   lb $a0 daGreeting #save array address
   lw $a1 buffer2 #save buffer address
   jal reverseByte #call the 'reverse' function

   
   la $a0 daBeef
   la $a1 buffer1 
   jal reverseWord
   
   #end of main
   li $v0, 10
   syscall
   reverseByte:
      #a0 = daGreeting address
      #a1 = buffer2 address
      srl $t0, $a0, 16 #t0 = end of daGreeting (16 bits right)
      addi $t2, $zero, 3 #t2 = i = 3
   loop: 
      beqz $t2, exit #repeat until i = 0
      
      sb $a1, ($t0) #save daGreeting[j] to buffer2[i]
      
      addiu $t0, $t0, -4 #daGreeting moves back 1 unit
      addiu $a1, $a1, 4 #buffer2 moves forward 1 unit
      addi $t2, $t2, -1 #i--
      j loop
   exit:
      jr $ra
      
   reverseWord:
      #a0 = daBeef
      #a1 = buffer1 address
      srl $t0, $a0, 16 #t0 = end of daBeef (16 bits right) 
      addi $t2, $zero, 3 #t2 = i = 3
      loop1: 
         beqz $t2, exit1 #repeat until i = 0
         
         sw $a1, ($t0) #save daBeef[j] to buffer1[i] 
         
         addiu $t0, $t0, -4 #daBeef moves back 1 unit 
         addiu $a1, $a1, 4 #buffer1 moves forward 1 unit
         addi $t2, $t2, -1 #i--
         j loop1
      exit1:
         jr $ra
```

When I run this I get:

`Error in C:\Users\kerfu\Desktop\mips\mips2.asm line 38: Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: address out of range 0x00000000`

Line 38 is this one btw: `sb $a1, ($t0) #save daGreeting[j] to buffer2[i]`

Any help is appreciated, even if it's just pointing out that the logic in my comments is wrong. Also, I can't edit anything before `.text` as a part of the project instructions.

Comment: `sw data, offset(address-register)`.  I think you have it backwards, using the data you want to store as part of the addressing mode.

Comment: [Mixed destination/source operand order in RISC-V assembly syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59802318) explains some of why this asm-source quirk might make some sense, but suffice it to say that most RISC machines do it this way in their asm source syntax.